# error with django model query

Tags: python, django, django-models

I encountered an error when doing the following retrieval:

```
class status(models.Model):
    pid = models.IntegerField()
    phase = models.TextField()
    rejected = models.IntegerField()
    accepted = models.IntegerField()
    type = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    date = models.DateTimeField(primary_key = True)
    time_taken = models.IntegerField(null = True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "crawl_status_ss"
```

query:

```
    statusIn = status.objects.get(pid=12345,phase='crawling')
```

Error:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored
until end of transaction block
```

Does anyone knows whats the reason?

EDIT:

In my previous section of my code, I have an exception when inserting an entry to another table, but i caught the exception:

```
for entry in blogEntries:        
            link = entry['link'].encode('utf-8')
            title = entry['title'].encode('utf-8')
            date1 = entry['date'][:10].encode('utf-8')
            content = entry['content'].encode('utf-8')
            try:
                post = postTitle(site_id=url,post_url=link,post_title=title)
                post.save()
                postId = post.post_id

                hashString = getMD5Hash(content)

                blogContent = postContent(post_content=content,post_id=post,hash=hashString,site_id = url,post_date=date1)
                blogContent.save()

            except:
                print 'Error:' + str(sys.exc_value)
                continue
```

Comment: why on earth is `date` your primary key?  Do people do this?

Comment: can you please advise on why I shouldn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django stats a database transaction for your view.  So when you catch the exception, it means the transaction is in a failed state and you can't run any more SQls.  You should really try to figure what the actual problem is when it fails either in your `post.save` or `blogContent.save` methods.  If you really don't care (since you just catch the exception and continue), you should manage transactions yourself.  See the docs for help on this:

- [Managing database transactions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/?from=olddocs)